# Why am I encountering errors when I try to use the Visual Studio Analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, analyzer

I have written a small application in C# using Visual Studio 2010. It is a small "hello world" application and running perfectly fine. But when I try to analyze it using the built-in Visual Studio Analyzer and run the "sample" analysis, it gives the following errors:

```
Failed to load symbols for C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll.
Failed to load symbols for C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll.
Failed to load symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll.
Failed to load symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll.
Failed to load symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll.
```

How can I resolve these errors so that I can use the analyzer on my application? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **See Also**: [Error Message : Cannot find or open the PDB file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15937707/1366033)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to enable to your visual studio to download symbols from Microsoft Symbols server.

1. Click on  Tools > Options
2. Under Debugging Menu > Select Symbols
3. Check Microsoft Symbol Servers

   [image: Options > Microsoft Symbol Servers]
4. Run the analyzer again and everything should be fine.