# Error Message : Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, windows-7-x64

I tried running sample programs provided at [NVIDIA's official site](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html). Most of the programs ran smoothly except few where I get similar error messages. How can I fix that? Here's a sample of error message I got after running a program named "MatrixMul".

Note: I have installed both x32 and x64 [NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) v5.0 on my Window7x64 OS.

```
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\bin\win32\Debug\matrixMul.exe', Symbols loaded.
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\cudart32_50_35.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvcuda.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'matrixMul.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x12fc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x18a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3104] matrixMul.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)
```

Comment: Just to double check, all the samples with those messages still ran correctly, right? If not then you have some other error and the inability to load the PDB files are a red herring.

Comment: No, all such samples never ran correctly. I don't know much abut CUDA programming as I am a beginner.

Comment: What command-line output did the samples give? None of those messages are fatal errors, so what did the samples output when you ran them? The last message that the executable exited with code 0 looks correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find or open the PDB file in Visual Studio C++ 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954821/cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file-in-visual-studio-c-2010)

Comment: Rebuild project fixed mine.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The PDB file is a Visual Studio specific file that has the debugging symbols for your project. You can ignore those messages, unless you're hoping to step into the code for those dlls with the debugger (which is doubtful, as those are system dlls). In other words, you can and should ignore them, as you won't have the PDB files for any of those dlls (by default at least, it turns out you can actually obtain them when debugging via the [Microsoft Symbol Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503)). All it means is that when you set a breakpoint and are stepping through the code, you won't be able to step into any of those dlls (which you wouldn't want to do anyways).

Just for completeness, here's the official PDB description from MSDN:

> A program database (PDB) file holds debugging and project state information that allows incremental linking of a Debug configuration of your program. A PDB file is created when you compile a C/C++ program with /ZI or /Zi

Also for future reference, if you want to have PDB files for your own code, you would would have to build your project with either the /ZI or /Zi options enabled (you can set them via project properties --> C/C++ --> General, then set the field for "Debug Information Format"). Not relevant to your situation, but I figured it might be useful in the future

Comment: "you won't be able to step into any of those dlls (which you wouldn't want to do anyways)" Wait... Why not? What if we want to understand how something works better?

Comment: @Andrew That comment was more directed towards the specifics of this question -- understanding Windows system DLLs is orthogonal to running the CUDA example applications

Comment: Even though I have followed your steps, there is still one error appears,  'FaceReg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FaceReg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FaceReg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_core2411d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FaceReg.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.

Comment: @DennisDo that sounds more like it couldn't load the opencv PDB file as opposed to the windows PDB files.

Comment: @DennisDo I am also having same problem `opencv_world300d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`. How did you solved your problem?

Comment: For that one you may need to build opencv from source if the binary distribution did not provide a pdb file.

Answer (score 36):

Working with VS 2013. Try the following Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> Module Load Messages -> Off It will disable the display of modules loaded.

Comment: I don't know why people downvote answers like this; maybe it didn't answer the question exactly but it's useful info. By the way, you can also just right click in the Output window's text area.

Comment: @Mike22LFC Will it solve the problem the loading Symbols.

Answer (score 20):

If that message is bother you, You need run Visual Studio with administrative rights to apply this direction on Visual Studio.

Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> Symbols and select check in a box "Microsoft Symbol Servers", mark load all modules then click Load all Symbols.

Everything else Visual Studio will do it for you, and you will have this message under Debug in Output window
"Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)"

Comment: I did as you said, but I'm not able to click the Load all symbols as it is disable right now. It show be browser option for cache symbols in this directory. I don't know what to select. I'm using visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 6):

1. Please check if the setting Generate Debug Info is Yes which under Project Propeties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Debugging tab. If not, try to change it to Yes.
2. Those perticular pdb's ( for ntdll.dll, mscoree.dll, kernel32.dll, etc ) are for the windows API and shouldn't be needed for simple apps.
   However, if you cannot find pdb's for your own compiled projects, I suggest making sure the Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Working Directory uses the value from Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Output Directory .
3. You need to run Visual c++ in "Run as Administrator" mode.Right click on the executable and click "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 3):

I'm also a newbie to CUDA/Visual studio and encountered the same problem with a couple of the samples.  If you run DEBUG-> Start Debugging, then repeatedly step over (F10) you'll see the output window appear and get populated.  Normal execution returns nomal completion status 0x0 (as you observed) and the output window is closed.

Comment: This was the most useful for me because I really wanted to see the output of this program to know if the test passed. Note that you actually need to set a break point for execution to be stopped before the window is closed. I set a break point on the first line of the main method.

Answer (score -1):

If this happens in visual studio then clean your project and run it again.

Build --> Clean Solution

Run (or F5)