# "source information stripped" message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a Visual C++ project  When i tried to build the (project) in my 64 bit window 7 machine its getting compiled without any error but when i run the code its throwing "Symbols loaded (source information stripped) and Cannot find or open the PDB file" errors for few .dll files. 
and i see this messages:

```
'Triclops test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Triclops test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Triclops test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).

The program '[12780] Triclops test.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

I'm new user with VC++ 2010 so, how can solve this problem help me please because this is very important.

I went through all the related questions that were posted here. And i have tried all the solutions they were told to be working for them but don't know why they all not working for me. Please help me out solving this.

Rose.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a non issue.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937707/error-message-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file Why closing with "lacks information"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem.

The message means that the pdb files for ntdll.dll/kernel32.dll/kernelbase.dll don't contain source code information while they main contain some other (call stack, maybe) information.

It's not related to your program "Triclops test.exe"'s exit.

Comment: Thank u for your answer and yes it is not related to my program but it disconnect the running of the program and i this warning message: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click ok to close the application.

Comment: One option is to debug your program. (step by step maybe)
Another is to write logs, and check which logs are printed while others are not. Then you can know where the error happened.

Comment: I try to debug step by step but the build is faild this time I dont know what happend to the project I see the following message: 1>Triclops test.cpp(127): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>Triclops test.cpp(127): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '/'
1>Triclops test.cpp(171): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>Triclops test.cpp(171): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '/'
1>Triclops test.cpp(234): error C2017: illegal escape sequence

Comment: and there is no any missing charecter in the program. thanks

Comment: You could post your code here, I think that will be more efficient.
Besides, I think you could try reading some examples/tutorials.

Comment: hi again again i think the last sentence:The program '[7316] Triclops test.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b). is the problem the program exit the run because this error code. can any one help me to solve this error.