# Error with loading the file in Opencv 2.4.10 while using visual studio 2013

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

Here is the problem when I'm trying to debug (I already enable the Microsoft Symbol Servers)

> 'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\opencv2410\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_core2410d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\opencv2410\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_highgui2410d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The code and installation which I followed is on this website: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

Any helps are appreciated!!!

Comment: not an error, just a warning. the pdb files are not supplied with the prebuild libs, that just means you cannot jmp into the opencv library code wile debugging. (if you need that feature, rebuild from src using cmake)

Comment: I rebuild and run without debugging. But the result is not similar to the result on that website

Comment: Oh okay, I haven't added the image in the directory. Anyway, thank you for your comment

Comment: FYI - dont mark your posts as solved on StackOverflow. Accept an answer that answers your question otherwise they do not show up as answered in the lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error and I doubt will ever become a problem for you.

The PDB file is a Visual Studio specific file that has the debugging symbols for your project. You can ignore those messages, unless you're hoping to step into the code for those dlls with the debugger (which is doubtful, as those are system dlls).

These files are not included in the pre-built library provided on the [OpenCV download page](http://opencv.org/downloads.html), they will however be generated when/if you [build them yourself](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).

You can find a much better explanation on what PDB files are on [this stackoverlow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937707/error-message-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file)

Comment: Thank you sir, I can run the application now