# TFS sonar build failed with .pdb file not found

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, tfs-2015

Our sonar build (XAML Build) for TFS is failing with below mentioned error

> Start Sonar-runner
>
> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
> ERROR: Unable to execute
> Sonar ERROR: Caused by: Cannot find the .pdb file "C:\Builds\1\ABC\Sonar_t\src\NET-WIN\Order\Entry\Entryl\Loss.......\Referentials\Commercial\Rules\bin\Debug\essel.Order.Referentials.Commercial.Rules.pdb" inferred from the property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly".
> ERROR: ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch. ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

The project/solution was created in Visual Studio 2008 version and our build server runs Visual Studio 2015 so I pass /toolsversion:3.5 as an MSbuild argument.

#### Environment details

- TFS 2015 update 1 (build server)
- sonar version 4.5.1, sonar runner - 2.4, C# plugin 3.3

The CI build for the same solution is successful but sonar build is showing partially succeed with missing .pdb file

What could be causing this ?

Comment: Do you build in Debug mode or Release mode? You may try to build in Debug mode to see whether the issue persists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571433/cannot-find-the-pdb-file-inferred-from-the-property-sonar-cs-fxcop-assembly

Comment: Have you re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch or -X switch? Do you get more log? As the error indicates to sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly, have you installed FxCop and specify the Path to FxCopCMD.Exe?