# opencv c++: cannot find or open pdb file of ucrtbased.dll and opencv_310d.dll

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I have a problem with opencv. When I try to run code from http://www.learnopencv.com/face-swap-using-opencv-c-python/ on visual studio, the program always give me output like this
`Project2.exe (Win32): Loaded C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll. Cannot find or open the PDB file`
and
`Project2.exe (Win32): Loaded C:\OpenCV310\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world310d.dll. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`

I really do not know what to do. If you have a solution, please help me to resolve this.

Comment: This question was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937707/error-message-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file

Comment: thanks for answer my questinon, i have to implement all sollution on your link before i ask in here, but the program still cant find or open the PDB file only for opencv_world310d.dll and ucrtbased.dll ._.