# opencv_world300d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, pdb-files

I am trying to build A project in Visual studio 2013 which uses some additional libraries, **OpenCV** and other files. When I build project, it was successful but I run the created executable it halted giving some error code. So I used *Windows debugger mode* of Visual studio while building. and gave me following error:

```
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\amy\Downloads\clandmark-   master\clandmark\build\examples\Debug\static_input.exe'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_world300d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
 'static_input.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_world300d.dll'
 The program '[5124] static_input.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Now I have checked the :
**Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> Symbols** and select check in a box "**Microsoft Symbol Servers**", mark load all modules then click Load all Symbols. found in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937707/error-message-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file)

When I searched about this problem

```
 opencv_world300d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

I found a solution that PDB file for **opencv_world300d.dll** does not come with prepacked version and for That I need to build OpenCV from *source*. After a long time of searching I decided to build it by myself and I build the OpenCV from source and It was build successful. It build around 56 project.

But there is no **PDB** or **DLL** file of name **opencv_world300d**

There are so many libraries but not the required one. I am stuck now and unable to counter my problem. Please help!

Comment: Not finding a PDB is normally an informational message, not an error. You might like to show the actual runtime error that you got and the relevant source code.

Comment: @RogerRowland Its a linker error which needs to be solved. It comes on runtime. It may not seem to you an error but it is the main cause why program crashes.

Comment: Linking is not a runtime function, PDB is not needed at runtime. I really don't think that this is the cause of your problem, but I may be wrong (I've only been writing software for 39 years).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there seems to be some confusion about **opencv_world**, lets start with some clarification:

**What is opencv_world**

Opencv_world is a dll that packs everything from opencv into on library file.
Good thing about this is that you only need to include one library and not 10 or 12 libraries in your project files.

**How to build opencv_world**

When configuring your build using cmake enable the option `BUILD_opencv_world` and make sure it builds fine to get the opencv_world.dll. This should give you the opencv_world.pdb as well.

**Do I need opencv_world?**

No! You can simply use the individual modules that you want without the need for opencv_world. Thus you will not need the opencv_world pdb at all if you do not want to use the opencv_world.dll.

**What are pdb files and do I need them**

A PDB ([program database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database)) file is a proprietary file format used by Microsoft that includes debug information. You do not need it if you do not need to debug the code inside a dll, it is howevery usefull when you want to locate a crash in your program.